# Some letters are jumbled when outputted to HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding, utf-8

The character `é` appears as a question mark in Chrome. I'm using PHP to get the content from MySQL to output to HTML. I tried using `mb_detect_encoding()` to determine the contents' encoding, some are ASCII and some are UTF-8. Why do they have different encodings? Is MySQL making them different or is PHP doing this?

The content containing the `é` is encoded as UTF-8. But if I use `utf8_encode()` on the content, the character displays correctly. If it's already UTF-8, why does using `utf8_encode()` make it display correctly?

Comment: `é` is ASCII  with 233 code if you convert or not is not different.

Comment: Are you populating the database also?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the connection to your db as utf8:

```
// Setup your connection
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw');
mysql_select_db('yourdb', $connection);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);

// now you get utf-8 encoded stuff
$query = sprintf('SELECT name FROM place where id = 1');
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape string using the `htmlentities()` PHP function so that the characters are changed into their respective HTML entities, such as è changes to `&egrave;`, regardless of if you are specifying an encoding type.